# Ribbon menu in Android app

Tags: android, menu, ribbon, application-design

I want to use ribbon menu(as on Microsoft Word 2007 or 10) in my android application. Anyone have any suggestions? If it impossible to implement, may be anyone have other ideas how to implement similar functionality? In Android development i am newbie, so i can not imagine how to modulate Ribbon menu with Activities(windows) and Android tools. 
May be  using of Ribbon menu in mobile Apps is not good idea, if so, what alternative i can use? 
Ribbon menu need because application is very large, and it's have many tools and options.
Thanks!:) 
 [image]

Comment: Are you sure you want to do so in Android? Ribbon UI isn't mobile/tablet-friendly, you'd think another approach. It's just a suggestion ;)

Comment: yes, my App target platform is Tablets. So which way i can to choose? how to modulate similar functionality?

Comment: I mean, Ribbon UI isn't suitable for touch screens, it's more for desktop development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TabLayout mixed + linear/relativelayout + using layout_weight properly.

Comment: yes, this is idea to build menu (but only visual component of menu).  in this case appears a trouble - i should to build this menu in every activity and this menus don't be related with each other.

Comment: Of course each activity of a tab must be different . But i think you can do a better change . You can make a linearlayout with customized buttons and when you click each one , they show an invisible relative layout. That's the easy way , and you dont have to make an activity for each menu, only a relativelayout.  The bad thing of this is that you must customize it well to have it like a rubon menu.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a built in ribbon menu in Android.
You could model it with a TabLayout ([Android dev info on Tabs](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)) that has a tab for each of the ribbon menu entries such as Home, Insert, ...

You can then show the different menus in the view displayed.

Comment: ok, thanks for information. But  if user switch tab from "Home" to "Insert", activity also will replaced with Insert tab activity -->> it mean that i must  push all information from Home activity to Insert activity.. I need a work area (static).